# Python matrix sums of arbitrary columns

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, sum

I'm writing an algorithm where I need to 'collapse' or 'reduce' a matrix based on cluster assignments for different nodes. However, the current implementation is by far the bottleneck of my complete algorithm (tested in Visual Studio Python profiler).

```
def reduce_matrix(mat: np.matrix, cluster_ids: np.array) -> np.matrix:
    """Reduce node adjacency matrix.

    Arguments:
        mat: Adjacency matrix
        cluster_ids: Cluster membership assignment per current node (integers)

    Returns:
        Reduced adjacency matrix
    """

    ordered_nodes = np.argsort(cluster_ids)
    counts = np.unique(cluster_ids, return_counts=True)[1]

    ends = np.cumsum(counts)
    starts = np.concatenate([[0], ends[:-1]])

    clusters = [ordered_nodes[start:end] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]

    n_c = len(counts)

    reduced = np.mat(np.zeros((n_c, n_c), dtype=int))
    for a in range(n_c):
        a_nodes = clusters[a]
        for b in range(a + 1, n_c):
            b_nodes = clusters[b]
            reduced[a, b] = np.sum(mat[a_nodes, :][:, b_nodes])
            reduced[b, a] = np.sum(mat[b_nodes, :][:, a_nodes])

    return reduced
```

What would be the fastest way to sum arbitrary rows and columns in a matrix?

I believe the double indexing `[a_nodes, :][:, b_nodes]` creates a copy of the matrix instead of a view, but I'm not really sure if there is a quicker workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba can  speed up such task in a very natural way, with no sorting issues. Here, a lot of irregular chunks  must be managed so Numpy is not very efficient:

```
@numba.jit  
def reduce_matrix2(mat, cluster_ids):
    n_c=len(set(cluster_ids))
    out = np.zeros((n_c, n_c), dtype=int)
    for i,i_c in enumerate(cluster_ids):
        for j,j_c in enumerate(cluster_ids):
            out[i_c,j_c] += mat[i,j]
    np.fill_diagonal(out,0)            
    return out
```

On a `5000x5000` mat :

```
In [40]: %timeit r=reduce_matrix2(mat,cluster_ids)
30.3 ms ± 5.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loop each)
```

Comment: Elegant solution for sure! Does require an extra dependency though, but it makes such a huge difference that I'm included to accept this as the solution.

However, this does assume the unique values cluster_ids to be a perfect range. That would be easily fixable with np.unique(cluster_ids, return_inverse=True)[1], or would you know of a more Pythonic solution?

Comment: Yes . np.unique will perfectly do the job in this case :  it's not the critical part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

We can reduce it to one loop, by summing more number of blocks but in intervals with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) and this should be more efficient.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
# Get ordered nodes
ordered_nodes = np.argsort(cluster_ids)

# Get indexed array
M = mat[np.ix_(ordered_nodes, ordered_nodes)]

# Get group boundaries on sorted cluster ids
sc = cluster_ids[ordered_nodes]
cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, sc[1:] != sc[:-1], True])

# Setup output array
n_c = len(cut_idx)-1
out = np.zeros((n_c, n_c), dtype=mat.dtype)

# Per iteration perform reduction on chunks off indexed array M and 
# defined by cut_idx as boundaries
for i, (s0, s1) in enumerate(zip(cut_idx[:-1], cut_idx[1:])):
    out[i] =  np.add.reduceat(M[s0:s1], cut_idx[:-1],axis=1).sum(0)

np.fill_diagonal(out,0)
```

#### Benchmarking

Proposed approach as func -

```
def addreduceat_app(mat, cluster_ids):
    ordered_nodes = np.argsort(cluster_ids)
    M = mat[np.ix_(ordered_nodes, ordered_nodes)]
    sc = cluster_ids[ordered_nodes]
    cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, sc[1:] != sc[:-1], True])
    n_c = len(cut_idx)-1
    out = np.zeros((n_c, n_c), dtype=mat.dtype)
    for i, (s0, s1) in enumerate(zip(cut_idx[:-1], cut_idx[1:])):
        out[i] =  np.add.reduceat(M[s0:s1], cut_idx[:-1],axis=1).sum(0)

    np.fill_diagonal(out,0)
    return np.matrix(out)
```

Timings and verification on a dataset with `5000` clusters with `500` being unique ones -

```
In [518]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: mat = np.random.randint(0,10,(5000,5000))
     ...: cluster_ids = np.random.randint(0,500,(5000))

In [519]: out1 = reduce_matrix(mat, cluster_ids)
     ...: out2 = addreduceat_app(mat, cluster_ids)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [520]: %timeit reduce_matrix(mat, cluster_ids)
     ...: %timeit addreduceat_app(mat, cluster_ids)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.39 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 195 ms per loop
```

Comment: I've accepted the other answer for it's brevity and great readability. However, this solution would come into play when you would be bound to numpy only. Thanks a bunch for sharing!